# Spring.NET and mono integration

Tags: c#, .net, mono, spring.net

I'm going to use Spring.NET in my bundle of WCF project. Mainly, I want to use AOP and IoC modules of Spring.NET.
I'm currently working only in windows environment, but in short time I'm going to use linux environment too. 
So, My question is around issues between Spring.NET and Mono.
Does anybody know about hard-to-overcome issues met in process of migration?

Comment: There were some attempts in the past, but Mono was never officially supported by Spring.net; [check the forum for details](http://forum.springframework.net/forumdisplay.php?13-Mono-Development).

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to "use Linux in short time", the best thing to do is start developing in Linux right away. That way, you will avoid from the first moment any technology that could not work in a cross-platform way. A good example of this is WCF, as it listed as **limited support** in the [Mono compatibility page](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility).

Comment: thank for your answer, I'll investigate compatibility of WCF and mono for myself.